# shell script error [: 12: unexpected operator?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(</var/www/sym_monitor/manthan.txt)


if [ "$value" == "true" ]; then

     ps -ef|grep sym |grep -v grep |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;


(cd /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin;sudo ./sym --port 8082 --server);

fi
```

When I run this script manually it is running fine but when I run this script inside cron it is giving the following error.

[: 12: unexpected operator

Any Idea why? Any suggestions?

Comment: This kind of approach to running a process is generally a really bad idea. You should be using a proper process supervision system (Upstart, Runit, systemd, launchd, etc -- yes, systemd wasn't available and stable in 2013, but the others all were) instead -- those can all much more reliably restart a service without potential to misfire and grep and kill the wrong process, and with immediate notification when that process dies.

Answer (score 3):

You are not running the script in `bash`, but in a different shell. Use single `=` instead of `==` for POSIX compliant shells.

Comment: Yes I'm running using bin/sh in cron. Now I changed it to bin/bash but it is not taking -eq so Im using same == I tried to run manually it is working fine. Let me check when cron finishes running it I will see whether it is working or not.

Comment: Now other problem. This script executing properly it is killing the processes (ps -ef|grep sym |grep -v grep |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;) but the next command didn't executed and no error message also? any idea?

Comment: Any comments on this please?